# Flight paths over the date line

Tags: geoserver, mysql-spatial

I have a table with lat/long values in MySQL.
The sequence column gives me the order in which the path must be traced.
[image].
 
I need to create a line from these values and display the flight path via a WMS service using GeoServer.
I am making use of a SQL view with the following query to generate the paths:

```
SELECT  GeomFromText(CONCAT('LINESTRING (',
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(longitude, ' ', latitude) ORDER BY sequence SEPARATOR ','),
')'
)) as flight_path
FROM 
flight_table where id = 2345
```

This works well and I am able to display the paths.
However when I have a flight path that crosses the international date line then I get the following output 
 [image]

What would be the ideal way to resolve this in GeoServer?

Comment: change your projection to one that is not discontinuous at the anti-meridian or modify your function to add a break at the anti-meridian

Comment: but the same projection would not hold true for flight paths crossing the meridian.

Comment: then you need to add a break

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182728/how-can-i-convert-postgis-geography-to-geometry-and-split-polygons-that-cross-th for an example in PostGIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First identify the flight paths that crosses date line.

```
select a.id as id , case when a.bd > 0 and a.ad > 0 then 1
    else
    0
    end as `cross` from (    
    SELECT flight_plan_id as id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN longitude BETWEEN 165 AND 180 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bd,
    SUM(CASE WHEN longitude BETWEEN -180 and -165 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ad
    FROM testdb.flight_plan_points where flight_plan_id in (2345) group by flight_plan_id) a
```

Create a new column "split" and split the line based on the following condition

```
 case when i.`cross` > 0 and wp.longitude < 0 then 1
        else 0 end as split
    from
```

and group by flightid and split. So for flight paths crossing the date line there will be a discontinuity at the date line. However for other flight paths there will be no break in the line.

So the full query would be as follows: This handles cases that crosses over the dateline or not.

```
set session group_concat_max_len= 4096;
SELECT  GeomFromText(CONCAT('LINESTRING (',
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.longitude, ' ', c.latitude)  ORDER BY c.sequence  SEPARATOR ','),
')'
)) as flight_path
FROM 
    (SELECT wp.flight_plan_id,wp.latitude,wp.longitude,wp.sequence,i.`cross`,
        case when i.`cross` > 0 and wp.longitude < 0 then 1
        else 0 end as split
    from 
    testdb.flight_plan_points wp 
    inner JOIN
    (select a.id as id , case when a.bd > 0 and a.ad > 0 then 1
    else
    0
    end as `cross` from (    
    SELECT flight_plan_id as id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN longitude BETWEEN 165 AND 180 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bd,
    SUM(CASE WHEN longitude BETWEEN -180 and -165 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ad
    FROM testdb.flight_plan_points where flight_plan_id in (2345) group by flight_plan_id) a ) i
    on wp.flight_plan_id = i.id) c
    group by flight_plan_id,c.split
```